# Using rolling sum to identify certain events based on starting/stopping data

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to extract specific events from my dataset, `water` using the code that is below.  (the data that I have below is not the actual dataset).

At the moment, my code classifies an `event` based on whether there is a zero or not in between values greater than zero.  It then sums those values and returns the total water used for each event.  But, this code currently classifies one event as two events, even if there is only a couple of seconds of zeroes in between them.  If the duration of the zeroes is less than 5 seconds between events, I want to classify them in the same event.

**How could I adjust my code to check whether the zero in between events is less than 5 seconds, and if it is, classify them in the same event?**

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-01-01 14:00:00', '2017-01-01 14:01:00', freq='S')
water = [0,0,0.2,0.3,0.4,0,0,0.3,0.2,0.5]*6+[0]
df = pd.DataFrame({'time_stamp':rng,'water_amount':water})

starts = (df['water_amount']>0)&(df['water_amount'].shift(1)==0) #find all starts of events
n_events = sum(starts) #total number of events
df.loc[starts,'event_number'] = range(1,n_events+1) #numerate starts from 1 to n
df['event_number'] = df['event_number'].fillna(method='pad').fillna(-1) #forward fill all the values
df.loc[df['water_amount']==0,'event_number']=-1 #set all event numbers to -1 where the water amount is 0

df.groupby('event_number').agg({'time_stamp':'first',
                                    'water_amount':'sum'}) #feature matrix
```

EDIT:
Photo that illustrates my problem:

[image]

Comment: Might want to look into resampling. Basically, if you re-sample using a resolution of five seconds then a zero that's smaller than 5 seconds will disappear from the data set

Comment: Can you hand create what the final dataframe would look like for your given data. The largest span of consecutive zeros in your current example is 3 seconds so to me your dataset would be one big group. Please clarify

Comment: @Lagerbaer this won't work. What if the zero run starts and ends in the middle of a 5-second interval? Resampling will hide either one of them or both, depending on the type.

Comment: Why not transform your data stream into value, run length pairs as it's coming in? Then it will be easy to identify runs of zero longer than a threshold.

Comment: @TedPetrou I've added a photo of what a piece of my data frame looks like.  Thanks for looking!

Comment: @blubberdiblub Could you possibly illustrate with an example?  I'm not totally following the "run length pairs" concept.  Thank you!

Comment: @Gary well, suppose your source data is 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.4, then you'd transform that into (1, 0.0), (1, 0.5), (2, 0.0), (3, 0.7), (1, 0.1), (6, 0.0), (1, 0.4) where the first value of each pair is how often the measurement occurs consecutively and the second value is the actual measurement. (And you can do this transformation on the fly, if need be.) Then it's easy to tell the (2, 0.0) run from the (6, 0.0) run, as the length of the run is already in there.

Comment: @blubberdiblub This is a very nice method.  I'll give it a try!

Comment: @gary please clarify: the data you provided above  in `df` would be classified as one group correct? And the only way you separate groups is with 5 consecutive zeros?

Comment: @TedPetrou The data above is currently being classified as 3 events, because it's classifying an event whenever the value changes from 0 to nonzero.  I would like it classified into two events (Event 1 and Event 2).  And 5 consecutive zeros is what I'd like to use as a minimum separator between events.

Comment: @gary I'm asking about the data you created in pandas, not your image. Is that data, the one stored in variable `df` one group?

Comment: @TedPetrou It was just sample data that I created to illustrate what I was doing with the code.  So, it's multiplied by 6, just to create more rows of data.

Comment: Just a suggestion for your next question. Post mock data that actually contains a replica of the real scenario that you will encounter. Then hand create the solution for the mock data and post it. Do not post images and do not post mock data that does not contain the scenario you are attempting to solve. Almost all pandas questions that are asked in this format are answered in under 30 minutes.

Comment: @Gary Take a look at the pandas solution I posted below and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that first labels each group of consecutive zeros. Then it counts how many zeros are in that group and determines if there are less than 5. It then labels the entire water Series increasing the group number only when a 5 consecutive zeros are found.

Once the groups are properly labeled, the aggregation is easy.

#### Fake data with several groups

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-01-01 14:00:00', '2017-01-01 14:01:00', freq='S')
water = [0,.2,.3,0,0,.4,0,0.3,0.2,0.5,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,4,0,0,0,0,5,4,0,0,2,4,0,0,
         0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,.4,.3,.1,.4,0,0,0,4,5,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,5,1,2,0,0]
df = pd.DataFrame({'time_stamp':rng,'water_amount':water})
water = df.water_amount
```

#### Divide into groups and aggregate

```
groups = water.ne(0).diff().fillna(0 == water.iloc[0]).cumsum().mul(water.eq(0))

counts = groups.value_counts()
counts.loc[0] = 0

groups5 = groups.map(counts).lt(5)

groups_final = groups5.diff().cumsum().fillna(0).add(1).mul(groups5).astype(int)

df_agg = df.groupby(groups_final).agg({'time_stamp':['first', 'last'],
                                    'water_amount':'sum'}).drop(0) 
df_agg.index.set_names(['Group Number'], inplace=True)
```

Output from `print(df_agg)`

```
                      time_stamp                     water_amount
                           first                last          sum
Group Number                                                     
1            2017-01-01 14:00:00 2017-01-01 14:00:09          1.9
3            2017-01-01 14:00:15 2017-01-01 14:00:27         23.0
5            2017-01-01 14:00:33 2017-01-01 14:00:33          1.0
7            2017-01-01 14:00:39 2017-01-01 14:00:50         12.2
9            2017-01-01 14:00:56 2017-01-01 14:01:00          8.0
```

Answer (score 1):

don't know pandas but I do have some prototype code

build a list of lists of index, data tuples, each sublist being a contiguous run of measurements, breaking on any 0 data

```
import itertools as it

water = [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0.9, 1.0]*2+[0]

i_water=((i,e) for i,e in enumerate(water))

chunk_i_water = [[i] + 
                 [e for e in it.takewhile(lambda x: x[1] != 0, i_water)] 
                 for i in i_water if i[1] != 0]

print('chunked: ', *chunk_i_water, sep='\n')
print('\n')

chunked: 
[(1, 0.1), (2, 0.2)]
[(5, 0.5)]
[(9, 0.9), (10, 1.0)]
[(12, 0.1), (13, 0.2)]
[(16, 0.5)]
[(20, 0.9), (21, 1.0)]
```

then merge the sublists by the diff in the indices

your application would use the indices to call the event times, and test on time differences instead

```
def MergeOnDiff(a, diff):
    b = [a[0]]
    for i in range(len(a)-1):
        if a[i+1][0][0] - a[i][-1][0] < diff+1:
            b[-1] += a[i+1]
        else:
            b.append(a[i+1])
    return b

diff = 3
b = MergeOnDiff(chunk_i_water, diff)

print('merged with diff = ', diff, *b, sep='\n')    

merged with diff = 
3
[(1, 0.1), (2, 0.2), (5, 0.5)]
[(9, 0.9), (10, 1.0), (12, 0.1), (13, 0.2), (16, 0.5)]
[(20, 0.9), (21, 1.0)]

# change diff:

merged with diff = 
2
[(1, 0.1), (2, 0.2)]
[(5, 0.5)]
[(9, 0.9), (10, 1.0), (12, 0.1), (13, 0.2)]
[(16, 0.5)]
[(20, 0.9), (21, 1.0)]
```

getting the event averages, index range from the sublists is easy

```
for e in b:
    ave = sum((d[1] for d in e)) / len(e)
    print('for irange' , e[0][0], 'to', e[-1][0], 'ave = ', ave )

for irange 1 to 2 ave =  0.15000000000000002
for irange 5 to 5 ave =  0.5
for irange 9 to 13 ave =  0.55
for irange 16 to 16 ave =  0.5
for irange 20 to 21 ave =  0.95
```

again, you would use the indices to look up event start/stop times

Comment: This is working very well with my large dataset!  Instead of the average, I would like the sum for each range.  It looks like all I need to do to get the sum is remove the ` / len(e)` and change `ave` to sum.

Comment: I'm also getting a weird `numpy.float64 object is not callable` error when I run your event averages for loop.  It was running fine, and then this error popped up after a few minutes.  Any idea what I could have done?